# Can't fire FancyBox on an element that also has a .toggle() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I'm having a strange issue that I can't seem to figure out. I tried searching on SO and other sites, but I can't seem to get this stupid issue resolved.

Here's my problem - I'm using FancyBox to load some pages via AJAX. I have that working fine.

I also have some elements that are using `.toggle();` to change it's class to "active" to change the styling.

Both on their own work fine. The problem is that I've got a flag icon that is supposed to load a FancyBox instance, at the same time it needs to add a class of "active" to the icon. The idea is that once the form is saved, a flag is applied and the user knows that there is a flag associated with this bit of data.

Here is my JS code:

```
            $('.activate').toggle(function() {
                 $(this).addClass('active');
            }, function() {
                 $(this).removeClass('active');
            });

            $('.activate.active').toggle(function() {
                 $(this).removeClass('active');
            }, function() {
                 $(this).addClass('active');
            });

            $('.popup').fancybox({
                 autoDimensions: true,
                 modal: true
            });
```

What you're looking at is two separate functions that toggle the class on/off (some of the elements will load as active, which why there are two functions).

Here is my HTML:

```
<a class="activate popup fancybox.ajax icon flag" href="flag-rock.aspx">text</a>
```

The class of "active" loads the toggle function, the class of "popup" is supposed to load the FancyBox function, and "fancybox.ajax" tells FancyBox to load the content via AJAX. "icon" and "flag" simply style the anchor.

So, here's my deal. If I remove "active" FancyBox works, otherwise, I get the toggle of the class, but no FancyBox firing. I'm also not getting any errors in firebug or Chrome's dev tools.

I even tried something like this:

```
            $('.activate').toggle(function() {
                $(this).fancybox({
                    autoDimensions: true,
                    modal: true
                }).addClass('active');
            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
```

What happened was that the icon would get the class of active, but not fire FancyBox. If I clicked it again, it DID fire FancyBox, but only after the element was clicked twice.

You can view the page here: http://ec2-50-16-99-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com/aptify/rocks/global-rocks.aspx Click on the "flag" icon to the right of the data rows.

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

Ok, so thanks to the help of everyone below here is the solution that works for me.

jQuery:

```
        $('.popup, .active').fancybox({
                autoDimensions: true,
                modal: true
            });

            $('.activate').click(function()
            {
                $(this).toggleClass('active off');
                event.preventDefault()
            });
```

HTML:

`<a class="activate off fancybox.ajax icon flag" href="flag-rock.aspx">Stuck Rock</a>`''

the `preventDefault()` keeps the hyperlink from working when the flag is not toggled on. Otherwise you'd get the traditional page load within the window which is not what we want.

There may be a better way to do that, but that was all I knew how to do to fix the issue of the page loading when the flag was toggled on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should only apply fancybox once in the doc.ready

Also, you should look into http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ for your class toggling.

But I think really what you are after is onStart and onClosed events to toggle your flag.  That way your flag is active when the page is open in fancy box.

Try something like this:

```
    $(function(){
          $('#fancything').fancybox({
               autoDimensions: true,
               modal: true
          });
          $('.activate').click(function(){
                $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('popup fancybox.ajax')
          });
    });
```

Comment: The reason I wasn't using toggleClass was there are some other actions I need to perform on the toggle, so it's not just the class that is being changed.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I'm following the first part of your answer. I am calling FancyBox only once, aren't I?

Comment: My point is that you want to setup the fancy box outside of the activate click handler.  Setting up fancy box gets it ready to respond to the anchors on your page that implement the popup class.  So you need to setup fancybox, and then respond to the click on the activate click, which should also popup the fancybox.

Comment: Well, I thought that's what I was doing. I had the FancyBox function before the "active" class toggles, but it still didn't work. However, I just used your original function, calling FancyBox, and then the toggleClass method, and that seemed to work. I'm not exactly sure why that worked but the previous example didn't?

Comment: thanks for the edited function. However, what I need to have happen is for the flag to stay active. The database will then tell the page to load with the class of "active" next time until the flag is removed. I'll have a web service set up that will remove the flag the next time the flag button is clicked. But I don't want the popup to show the next time, because this second click will remove the flag.

Comment: Don't use the `$(this)` selector three times in a row, chain the function calls... `$(this).addClass('active').removeClass('popup fancybox-ajax')`.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the fancybox-up before the `click` event handler so it's ready to go on the first click? You are setting-up the fancybox on the first click so it's ready on the second click, just run the `fancybox` plugin on the elements at the same time that you bind the `click` event handlers via `.toggle()`:

```
        $('.activate').fancybox({
            autoDimensions: true,
            modal: true
        }).toggle(function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
```

I just tested this and when I run this code on your page it makes the popup display on the first click of the flag icons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to call the FancyBox function only once. I'm not a jQuery whiz by any stretch of the imagination, but does this really make a big difference? I guess it doesn't matter as long as it works, right?

Comment: Also, I should mention that I have some places on the site that I need to toggle the "active" class, but I don't want to fire FancyBox. I was hoping to write as little functions as possible. What do you recommend I do here?

Comment: If you want to call the `fancybox` plugin only once then this is the best way. Passing it all the elements that might need a `fancybox` at once. You could also use the `open` method that `fancybox` exposes: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs. This gets a bit convoluted when the user clicks a second or more times on the flag element.

Comment: I would just setup different `click` event handlers for the elements that need a `fancybox` and the ones that don't.